# One of his all/One of all his/one of all of his

Tags: word-order

I am not sure whether any of these are wrong or simply unidiomatic.

1 **One of his all cars** is black.

2 **One of all his cars** is black.

3 **One of all of his cars** is black.

Comment: What did you find when you researched this issue? (If you didn't know what to search for, you may want to start with the use of multiple determiners, such as "his" and "all", in a noun phrase.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["All of the ...." or " All the ... "?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/all-of-the-or-all-the) Also ['all' , 'all the', 'all of the', and 'the whole'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36721/all-all-the-all-of-the-and-the-whole) and ["All" vs. "All the" vs. "All of the"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/325728/all-vs-all-the-vs-all-of-the), ***among others.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A noun phrase usually has just one determiner.  So expressions like "The my apple" are incorrect.  But "all" can function as a determiner or as a "pre-determiner" So "all apples" or "all my apples" are both correct.  But "my all apples" is incorrect.

"One of" and "all of" and "all" are pre-determinative, but "his" isn't. So (1) is a grammar error.  2 and 3 are merely un-idiomatic.

There is no semantic purpose of "all" or "all of" in these sentences. It doesn't mean anything. So the only idiomatic phrase would be "One of his cars"

Comment: You would only use _all_ if you wanted to point out that something applied to _only_ one of a large number of things. "Of all the cars repaired by the garage that week, only one was pink."

Comment: Optional ***all*** is effectively an "intensifier" here - stressing the ***large*** size of the "pool" from which something is "selected". Idiomatically it almost always occurs in conjunction with another intensifier such as ***only, just, merely,...,*** stressing the ***small*** size / amount of the *actual* selection *(**just** one of **all** the many possibilities)*.

Comment: Why is it that "all her children" is correct? - "And she told all her children, "OK. This is David's space, OK?"

Comment: All= predeterminer,  her= determiner.  "All her children" is correct for *exactly* the reason that "All my apples" is correct, as given above.